# What is the pattern in the question box?

Tags: pattern

I am puzzled as to what pattern that should appear in the box with the  question mark in the picture below. Can anyone solve this puzzle? If so, please explain why the solution is as it is.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> D

Reasoning:

> looks like they are combining as they go top to bottom. If a line isn't there, add it, if it is there already (overlapping) remove it. This works for the first two columns and gives answer D for the last one.

Interesting progressive matrix puzzle. Where is this one from?

Comment: You forgot to answer why the answer is the one you gave.

Comment: Edits made to add the reasoning.

Comment: Thank you, MobileGlick. I think your answer shows a very plausible logic here, although there may also be other interpretations out there. This question is from a workbook for primary students to sit in enrollment exams for selective high schools in Sydney.

Comment: +1 It's basically XORing the first two cells in each column to find the 3rd (equivalently, XOR any two to get the third due to XOR's symmetry). I can't see any other reasonable interpretation.